# sporadic System.IO.IOException when calling System.IO.Directory.GetFiles and System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory

Tags: c#, vb.net, ioexception, getfiles

I've got .net 4.0 (vb.net & c#) code (about 15 different programs) running on a virtual server (Windows 2003 R2) that attempts to process files (maybe 1000/day) on other servers in the local network, running under a domain account.  The directories are all various Windows shares using machine name and alias (\server\share).

95% or more of the time things work just great, but for the past two months I've been seeing more instances of "The network path was not found" errors thrown by either System.IO.Directory.GetFiles or System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory.

Has anyone experienced and resolved the same thing?  At this point I wonder about things like Active Directory authentication and bad switch ports, but don't know how to "prove" that is really what is going on.

Is there any add'l software trapping I could be doing?

Should I look at hard-coding DNS addresses?

Comment: That's exactly what Windows says when it can't browse the share. I would start by using IP's but it could potentially be anything down the line. You could start by pinging the computer first and if it doesn't respond then don't attempt what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, for anyone else suffering this problem, the current theory is outdated anti-virus software on the server w/ the shares.  I'll know if this resolves it next Monday (2012-07-30).

Comment: For posterity, updating Symantec fixed my problem.  Hope this helps someone else...